# Draw security pattern using usb c to hub with hdmi

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, pattern-lock, hdmi, usb-c

Not sure if it's a note 10 issue or an android issue. My note 10 screen no longer works. I connect it to usb c to usb hub with hdmi. The monitor now shows clock and lock. The time is correct. I press the buttons on my wireless mouse and move it around but no lock screen pattern.

With my note 9 I pressed the page up button and was able to see home screen. Samsung says the phone needs to confirm on the screen. Note 9 did not do that. Another rep say its a power issue again the time is correct. They don't have a correct answer for me. Another says older phones showed lock pattern on monitor and new ones don't.

I seen youtube videos of people accessing the lock screen on monitor. They just draw the pattern using mouse.

How do I move from the clock and lock icon to the lock pattern draw screen?

Comment: Pattern lock is always a bad choice when the screen breaks. Password and PIN can be entered blindly using USB keyboard. The newer phones don't show pattern on external monitors could be a security measure to avoid automated attacks on the used pattern. If you still see the mouse cursor you may try to draw the pattern blindly. Otherwise accessing the phone will get complicated.

Comment: @Robert will look for the mouse arrow but don't see it. My note 9 by passes by pressing mouse back button but note 10 does nothing. Could it be the wirless mouse? What can I do to get to pattern screen?